# UITableView bring cells at bottom to front of View Hierarchy

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a question regarding UITableView and UITableViewCells. The default behavior of iOS is to put the cells on top to the front of the View Hierarchy like in the screen below

[image]

Is there a way to make the UITableView to bring the cells at the bottom of the UITableView to the front of the view hierarchy. What I'm looking for is an exact inverse of the Hierarchy in the picture above. The cell at the bottom needs to be the front most view, the cell above it needs to be behind the bottom most and so on.

Or is there a way that I can manually make a cell, using its indexpath, to bring it to the front of the hierarchy.

I tried using bringSubviewToFront but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you trying to put the cells in reverse order?

Comment: @CyrilIvarGarcia Yes that is what I want

Comment: Why is the view hiearchy between the table view cells relevant for you? Are your cells overlapping?

Comment: @Codo yes they overlap. But Overlapping is required in the app. It's not something I can get rid of because that is what the client wants. So what I want is that the cells at the bottom, which are overlapped by the cells on the top, should be above the cells at the top in the view hierarchy so they are visible

Comment: Try bringSubviewToFront in a reverse loop for all visible cells in cellForRow

Comment: UITableView is not designed to work with overlapping cells. You might get it to work with some tricks. But chances are you'll have to find new tricks for each new iOS version and even implement different tricks depending on the iOS version your app runs on. So it'll be painful and expensive. I strongly suggest you propose an alternative, non-overlapping layout to your client.

Comment: @malhal I tried your suggestion. It didn't work. Nothing happens to the view hirearchy

Comment: I suppose it has to be done in layout subviews

Comment: @ShayanJalil Have you figured out the solution? I want my cell at indexPath (i) to overlap the cell at indexPath (i-1). bringSubviewToFront is not working for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I stuck with the same problem and found a solution.

In my case I need to bring to front a cell which is an instance of specified class. Since all cells are just subviews of `UITableView`, I'm going through its subviews and bring the necessary cells to front:

```
func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView,
    willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,
    forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    tableView.subviews
        .filter { $0 is MyTableViewCell}
        .forEach { tableView.bringSubviewToFront($0) }
}
```